How to cut the the 4 top pieces of a pyramid?
I'm trying to figure out how to cut the 4 pieces that form the top of a pyramid.  I want to make a roof for a bird house. In fact, it's for some kind of a tower whose base is
4" x 4". Since the pieces will be cut 3/4" thick and at the top the thickness will be theoretically 0" i can not figure out how to cut those pieces. Since my English is not that good, here's a drawing. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/1tgbmdnqq2cbfisxqnie1/untitled.pdf?rlkey=utclm6aeyfpymsf1jwukythp4&dl=0

Hi, welcome to WSE. Could you attach the image directly in your question instead of linking to a PDF? Many people (myself included) will avoid opening unknown PDFs on the internet for security reasons.

Also, what tools do you have to do the cutting? Hand saw? Table saw? Bandsaw?

You don't want to make a pyramidal roof this way, not from wood, especially not from plywood if that was the idea. It's not impossible to make the pieces this shape (although it would prove extremely challenging, and, I don't believe it's possible using only cutting as I think you believe) but assuming you were able to shape your pieces accurately the points will be far too fragile and will respond to water/weathering effects very poorly.

I made something similar with no joinery on a bandsaw.  Using a solid piece of wood (mine was 6x6 cedar).

Use a simple pattern - it might be just a triangle shape.
Cut the outline on a bandsaw - be sure to save one or both of the scraps.
Supporting the piece with one of the scraps, eyeball trace the pattern shape onto the piece just cut.
Supporting the piece with that scrap, cut the outline again on the bandsaw.
Sand out any imperfections

With this technique, you need not limit your result to a simple pyramid.


I think that's what I'm gonna do. It will definitely do the trick in my case. But let' say the base would be 1' x 1'.  i would have no other way that cutting those weird pieces. Have a nice day !

@pascal - actually it's possible to do such cuts with a bandsaw up to 1' x 1'  provided you have a riser on the bandsaw.    Beyond 6 inchs, I'd be considering other approaches.  At some point, it's just a hip roof.

This is also quite straightforward with a hand saw (moderately coarse crosscut pattern or even rip if the angle is not very flat). The piece can be held in a vice or you can screw something to its bottom and hold that in the vise.
